# Dynamical value in define var_name block

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app i have such thing

```
#define ACCT_ID @"someaddress@gmail.com"
```

Is there any way to set dynamical value to this define block?

FOr ex. i make request to webserver, which returns me some string, and later i set this string into #define block.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Use NSUserDefaults instead of #define, as answered by kirti.

Comment: FYI... `#define` is a macro- the value remain unchanged what so ever, you cant modify it.

Comment: Do you know what `#define` means? It's quite hard to get dynamic variables from the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with following:

```
#define ACCT_ID [[SingletonClass myinstance] getEmail]
```

Answer (score 3):

you also use nsuserdefault like:

set value

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"abc@gmail.com" forKey:@"ACCT_ID"];
```

get value

```
 NSString *str= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"ACCT_ID"];
```

remove value

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"ACCT_ID"]
```

Comment: is this visible over all project? Do i have to clean it after some time?

Comment: it visible all project and you calean value

Answer (score 2):

Well of course not, since all lines begin with # happening during pre-processor compilation.
Therefor, the value given to ACCT_ID detemind before even your program compiled and it can not be changed